# how to read the Excel sheet in JSF

Tags: jsf

How to read the Excel sheet data in jsf.pls can u give the sample application

Answer (score 1):

Reading Excel sheet data has nothing to do with JSF. Try Apache POI or JExcel to read Excel. Google and find there are lot of tutorial for these around the web.

Comment: iam using JSF and Richfaces.In richfaces <rich:fileupload> tag to upload the excel sheet.now i am uploading the Excel sheet and getting the data.but i need that data will added to <rich:dataTable> arraylist.

Comment: Can you show me your code to this ?  I can help better if I see the code.